# Next.js custom server

Tags: javascript

I have a Next.js application and I want to connect it to a Node.js backend.
If i put the file server.js in the same folder of the Next.js application I can run the application through these scripts:

"scripts": {
"dev": "node server.js",
"build": "next build",
"start": "set NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
"lint": "next lint"
}

I want to put all the backend files in another folder (server.js too) , but in this case I can't run the application.

What I have to do? Thanks